# How to stop content overflowing container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I currently have content in a section element. When the page is resized, the content inside overflows the section. This behaviour occurs even when the section height is set to **auto**. I know the solution is very simple but I don't know why I can't figure it out. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

http://www.cssdesk.com/PBn23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `height = 100%` from section css styling. And it won't overflow. Setting it to 100% makes the height of the section 100% of its container meaning the viewport height in this case. Hence when resized some elements extend over to more than the height of the page and the height of the section remains to be the height of the viewport.

section css code :

```
section{
    background:#0e0e0e;
    min-height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Hello this work fine. However, the top:15% relative position on the #wrap then stops working. Using px works, but the overflow problem returns.

Comment: Well if you want to position your #wrap down remove postion:relative and instead use top-margins. For responsive design set margins in percentages.